# Caret's train and confusionMatrix functions

Tags: r, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I am trying to learn how caret works by following Max Khun's Applied Predictive Modeling book, but was not able to understand how caret's confusionMatrix function works.

I trained the training data set (training[, fullSet]), which has 8190 rows and 1073 columns, by using glmnet as follows:

```
glmnGrid <- expand.grid(alpha = c(0,  .1,  .2, .4, .6, .8, 1),
                    lambda = seq(.01, .2, length = 40))

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", 
                 number = 10,
                 summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                 classProbs = TRUE,
                 index = list(TrainSet = pre2008),
                 savePredictions = TRUE)

glmnFit <- train(x = training[,fullSet], 
             y = training$Class,
             method = "glmnet",
             tuneGrid = glmnGrid,
             preProc = c("center", "scale"),
             metric = "ROC",
             trControl = ctrl)
```

Then, I printed the confusion matrix from the fit:

```
glmnetCM <- confusionMatrix(glmnFit, norm = "none")
```

When I looked at the confusion matrix, I got the following result:

```
               Reference
Prediction     successful unsuccessful
  successful          507          208
  unsuccessful         63          779
```

But, I don't understand why the confusion table only has 1757 observations (1757 = 507 + 208 + 63 + 779) because caret's confusionMatrix.train documentation says that "When train is used for tuning a model, it tracks the confusion matrix cell entries for the hold-out samples." Since the training data set has 8190 rows and I used a 10-fold CV, I thought that the confusion matrix should be based on 819 data points (819 = 8190 / 10), which is not the case.

Clearly I don't fully understand how caret's trainControl or train works. Can somebody explain what I misunderstood?

Thanks so much for your help.

Young-Jin Lee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in the control parameter. You are using `method = "cv"` and `number = 10` but you are also specifying the exact resamples that will be used to fit the model (via the `index` argument). I assume that this is the grant data from [the book](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/). In chapter 12 we describe the data splitting scheme where the `pre2008` vector indicates that 6,633 of the 8,190 samples will be used for training. That leaves 1,557 left out during model tuning:

```
> dim(training)
[1] 8190 1785
> length(pre2008)
[1] 6633
> 8190-6633
[1] 1557
```

The predictions on the non-`pre2008` samples are what you are seeing in the table. If you are trying to reproduce what we have, page 312 has the correct syntax:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "LGOCV",
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     index = list(TrainSet = pre2008))
```

If you just want to do 10-fold CV, get rid of the `index` argument.

**tl;dr** The control function says 10-fold CV but the `index` argument says one hold-out of 1,557 samples should be used.

Max